# How do we share our worlds with one another?

Tags: discussion

This community is great for getting thoughtful and accurate answers about world building. If you need anything explained from intergalactic teleportation to magic-based agriculture, you can find it here. However, I find myself craving the ability hear the thoughts and ideas of other worldbuilders. In this community it is not considered productive to simply share our worlds with one another. I was wondering if anybody would like to share some tips on where worldbuilders can discuss their creative experience, not through facts and research. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you asking whether such areas exist? Are you suggesting forming a new forum/stack Exchange? What are you hoping for precisely?

Comment: Sorry if that wasn't clear enough. I was asking if such areas exist.  Though that would be a great function within this forum/stack exchange.

Answer (score 4):

The best place within Stack Exchange to chat about this is...chat.  While the main site has stricter rules about what's on-topic and productive to ask about -- because the main site is not a discussion forum -- chat is all *about* discussion.  Anybody with at least 20 reputation can use chat.  I recommend starting with the [main Worldbuilding room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17213/worldbuilders-general-chat), but if people want to set up a separate room to focus on specific types of discussion that can be done too.

There have also been efforts to start a collaborative world-development project (using Git) and a blog; I'll leave it to the organizers of those projects to say more about that.

Answer (score 1):

The biggest problem as I see it is that Stack Exchange just isn't set up for discussion. The format doesn't support it. Even here (and despite the 'discussion' tag)  I don't know whether to discuss by posting an answer or by making a comment.

Have you discovered **chat** yet?  Actually I'm not entirely sure how to use it myself but I presume you can contact a person by name and invite them to talk about a mutual interest.

So far I've only reached chat when sent there automatically from a discussion that was going on too long in comments. Annoyingly I've just tried to search for it and can't find how to access it!

Comment: The menu at the top left, click on it. Current Community - worldbuilding, there should be a chat link to the right of that.

Comment: Note the tag wiki for the [discussion] tag on Meta: "The question you're asking is designed to solicit opinions or best-practices on a particular topic, with the goal of reaching community consensus." That's a very different type of "discussion" compared to the discussions that happen in "conventional" online discussion forums.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling - I see. In that case I shall submit a question suggesting a different name for the 'discussion' tag.

Comment: If you do, because such a change would be network-wide, make that case on [meta.se].

Comment: Hold on - I just looked. Not all communities have a 'discussion' tag. (Example English Language & Usage) It's not network-wide. I think that my new question should remain here.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK [meta.english.se] has a "discussion" tag that [has been used 1320 times](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/discussion) as of now. The [earliest known usage](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/revisions/1/1) of the discussion tag on that site was on Aug 5 2010, on their meta post ID 1.